# How to order date in pivot SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

data

```
NOINDUK|PRIODE | TGL    
100101  12019   1/21/2019
100101  12019   1/22/2019
100101  12019   1/23/2019
100101  12019   1/24/2019
100101  12019   1/25/2019
100101  12019   1/26/2019
100101  12019   1/27/2019
100101  12019   1/28/2019
100101  12019   1/29/2019
100101  12019   1/30/2019
100101  12019   1/31/2019
100101  12019   2/1/2019
100101  12019   2/2/2019
100101  12019   2/3/2019
100101  12019   2/4/2019
100101  12019   2/5/2019
100101  12019   2/6/2019
100101  12019   2/7/2019
100101  12019   2/8/2019
100101  12019   2/9/2019
100101  12019   2/10/2019
100101  12019   2/11/2019
100101  12019   2/12/2019
100101  12019   2/13/2019
100101  12019   2/14/2019
100101  12019   2/15/2019
100101  12019   2/16/2019
100101  12019   2/17/2019
100101  12019   2/18/2019
100101  12019   2/19/2019
100101  12019   2/20/2019
100102  12019   2/19/2019
100102  12019   2/20/2019
100103  12019   2/19/2019
100103  12019   2/20/2019
```

how to order by tgl in the pivot, i have code in sql like this.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[procshift]

@priode nvarchar(6),

@cols   nvarchar(max)='' ,

@query  nvarchar(max)=''

AS

BEGIN

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME((tgl)) 

                    from tblabsen where priode = @priode 

            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE

            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 

        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT [no_induk],priode, ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
              select [no_induk], tgl, kodealasan,priode
              from tblabsen where priode = '''+@priode+'''    
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(kodealasan)
                for [tgl] in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '       
END
execute sp_executesql @query;
```

---

---

if i execute this i got result like this

```
no_induk priode 1-Feb-19 2-Feb-19 3-Feb-19    
100101   12019   P         P       P
```

display data not order, how to oder by tgl

```
no_induk priode 21-jan-19 22-jan-19 23-jan-19     
100101   12019   P         P         P
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an `ORDER BY` in your statement that generated the columns:

```
SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME((tgl)) 
                   FROM tblabsen
                   WHERE priode = @priode 
                   GROUP BY tgl
                   ORDER BY tgl ASC
                   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'');
```

I also suggest parametrising your dynamic statement. Change `where priode = '''+@priode+'''` to

```
WHERE priode = @priode
```

and then change your `sp_executesql` to:

```
EXEC sp_executesql @query, N'@priode nvarchar(6)', @priode = @priode;
```

*Edit, I just noticed, why is `@cols` and `@query` a parameter here? Remove those from the parameter list and `DECLARE` them in your SP.*

Comment: thanks.. i have been change code, as you suggest, but not running well, execute  '  exec procshift '012019'  // 012019 is data @priode

Comment: @ahmadsubuhanlubis kindly you can try to mark the answer, dear friend.

Comment: What do you mean "is not running well" @ahmadsubuhanlubis you mean slowly? If it is, then that would mean it either ran slowly before, or putting the rows in order is an expensive operation (how many rows do you have to be causing that..?). I've not introduced any breaking changes to the above code, which means there's something else you've done here which you've not informed us of if the code isn't working (and was before). I assume it's not erroring though, as you'd have provided an error message then.

Comment: Also, @ahmadsubuhanlubis why are `@cols` and `@query` a parameter? Younever use the passed values, and having a user pass a dynamic query is **a very bad idea**.

Comment: thanks very much it's running well, it turns out the error is distinct, SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME((tgl))  should not use distinct

Comment: That'll work, provided you don't have multiple rows with the same vale for`tgl` @ahmadsubuhanlubis. Try adding `GROUP BY tgl` instead if that'll be a problem.

Comment: @larnu, i have been try your suggest all work well, Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code to get all date columns in ascending order.

```
DECLARE @cols   nvarchar(max)='' 
    SELECT @cols = COALESCE(@cols + '[', '')+ FORMAT(tgl,'dd-MMM-yyyy')+'],'
      FROM tblabsen
      GROUP BY date
      ORDER BY date 
       IF (LEN(@cols)>1)
      BEGIN 
      Set  @cols = STUFF(@cols, LEN(@cols), 1, '')
      END
```